# Angular2 Exception: TypeError el.createShadowRoot is not a function (Safari/Edge)

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 app that works great in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari I get this error:

> TypeError el.createShadowRoot is not a function

And similarly in Edge:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'createShadowRoot'
>   at BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.createShadowRoot (http://localhost:5000/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:22893:7)

More from Edge: 
[image]

Is there some shim or polymer I am missing?

Comment: could you try [this link](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/concepts/experimental_features) for updating experimental flag in safari

Comment: According to MDN [Element.createShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot) is not supported in either IE nor Safari. Besides that it has been deprecated.

Comment: @EricMartinez thanks for the reference.  How do I tell Angular2 not to use createShadowRoot?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`createShadowRoot()` should only be called if you use `ViewEncapsulation.Native`.

Either use `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` or ensure polyfills are loaded (I can't guide you how, because I don't use the TS toolchain, only Dart)

Comment: Many thanks!  Turns out I was using snippets in VS Code and inadvertently was using ViewEncapsulation.Native

Comment: excellent answer, is it documented in the angular docs somewhere? or which polyfill(s) we should use for it?

Comment: I lost track of the web components support status in various browsers. Last year the web_components polyfill with full shadow DOM (not shady DOM) was required except for Chrome. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html doesn't mention it. I think native is officially only supported for browsers with native support, which makes some sense because Angular has his own emulation which is much faster. The disadvantage is that it doesn't allow to choose between native and emulated depending on browser support.

Comment: I already added the polyfill and still facing same issue, please see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webcomponent-polyfill

Comment: See my previous comment. ShadowDom changed substantially. I don't think you still neec polyfills, but you need recent docs about how to create custom elements.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue recently, got this error on Firefox
`el.createShadowRoot is not a function`

From the documentation, I learned that createShawdowRoot is deprecated, replaced by attachShadow()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot

Looking at the encapsulation of all the components in my Angular project, one component stood out and was using the ViewEncapsulation.Native , which was also deprecated so I replaced it by ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom as recommended, check
https://angular.io/api/core/Component#encapsulation

and that cured it for me.

So I suppose that the Native encapsulation compiles to createShawdowRoot no longer supported by Firefox.

Comment: Thank you this was also the issue in my application.

Answer (score 2):

if you are facing this issue in simple HTML file then below line of code can be helpful

```
element.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
```