# Angular 2 ViewEncapsulation.Native vs ViewEncapsulation.Emulated issue in chrome ipad & chrome browser

Tags: angular, google-chrome, ipad, angular2-template

I am using an Angular 2 component which and following property and this is working fine in Chrome desktop browser.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-header',
  templateUrl: './someheader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./someheader.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native 
})
```

But in my iPad Chrome browser it is giving me following error on page load

```
hostEI.createShadowRoot is undefined
```

But when I change it to

```
ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
```

it starts to work on my iPad but my UI breaks in desktop.

I checked following stackoverflow link

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824758/angular2-exception-typeerror-el-createshadowroot-is-not-a-function-safari-edge)

But my question is can I dynamically add this `encapsulation` property according to some condition in component decorator.

Thanks

Comment: [Web-components polyfills](https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills/) should do the trick

Comment: thanks this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all browser does support `ShadowDom` (like IE, Safari, etc), in that case `createShadowRoot` gets failed.

You could fix this problem easily by adding polyfills for webcomponent from below link

https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills/