# Getting console Error in only Safari when trying to view Angular 4 app

Tags: angular, shadow-dom

My Angular app works fine on Chrome but when viewing in Safari I get  an error in the console:

```
TypeError: hostEl.createShadowRoot is not a function. (In 'hostEl.createShadowRoot()', 'hostEl.createShadowRoot' is undefined) —
```

The following post does NOT answer my question: [Angular2 Exception: TypeError el.createShadowRoot is not a function (Safari/Edge)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824758/angular2-exception-typeerror-el-createshadowroot-is-not-a-function-safari-edge)
I have read many articles on this and have yet to find a solution that fixes my problem. I have not changed the viewEncapsulation anywhere on my app so it is by default using Emulated. I am using Angular 4.4.6

[image]

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

My pollyfills.ts file:

```
/**
* This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the 
app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are 
 sorted by browsers.
  *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be 
 loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last 
 versions of browsers that
  * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 
 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-
  support.html
 */
 /*******************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

 /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements 
 */
 // import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

 /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
  // import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


 /** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
 // Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular 
 decorators), you can remove.
 import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

  /**
  * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-
  browser/animations`.
  * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. 
   http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
   **/
  import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-
  js`.

   /*********************
   * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
   */
   import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



   /*********************
   * APPLICATION IMPORTS
   */

  /**
   * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
   * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
   */
   import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
   /**
   * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
   */
   import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Exception: TypeError el.createShadowRoot is not a function (Safari/Edge)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824758/angular2-exception-typeerror-el-createshadowroot-is-not-a-function-safari-edge)

Comment: I have gone over that post many times and I am unable to figure out how to apply the answer to my issue. Maybe I am missing something or just don't understand the asnwer..

Comment: I have gone through my pollyfill.ts file an uncommented all that look necessary for Safari and other browsers. I have never opted for using ViewEncapsulation.native.

Answer (score 3):

Ended up being the Ng4LoadingSpinner module/service I installed on my app. I removed the module and installed a new spinner module and everything is working perfectly. Ended up installing the [ngx-loading](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-loading) module.

Comment: which new spinner module installed?